# firebird gfix sweep don't clean

Tags: firebird

I've got a problem whit the gfix sweep command, because it doesn't clean the garbage collector. What problem it can be. The database backup size is 900mb smaller than the database itself. What is the problem if the gfix sweep started manually don't work?

Comment: "the database backup size is 900mb minor than the database itself." - that is normal. Backup is not the database. It is compressed and non-primary data used to speed-up real work is wiped out. That tells nothing about what specific kinds of "garbage" being (or not being) swept by gfix. Detailed per-page reports of gstat might show if there were some rows freed by gfix or not. With auto-sweep by default coming every 20K transactions (if I recall ok) there would usually not be a lot of work for gfix anyway. Unless some exotic untypical workload issued.

Comment: more so, while gfix does reclaim orphaned rows WITHIN pages, it does not move rows across page (that is not practically possible) and thus does not free pages. It makes no practical sense for a workable database anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A backup is smaller because it doesn't contain indexes, but just the database data itself, and it only contains data of the latest committed transaction, no earlier record versions. In addition, the storage format of the backup is more efficient, because it is written and read serially and doesn't need the more complex layout used for the database itself.

In other words, in almost all cases a backup will be smaller than the database itself, sometimes significantly smaller (if you have a lot of indexes or a lot of transaction churn, or a lot of blobs).

Garbage collection in Firebird will remove old record versions, sweep will also cleanup transaction information. Neither will release allocated pages, that is: the database file will not shrink. See [Firebird for the Database Expert: Episode 4 - OAT, OIT, & Sweep](https://web.archive.org/web/20231004130607/https://ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_21)

If you want to shrink a database, you need to backup **and** restore it, but generally there is no need for that: Firebird will re-use free space on its data pages automatically.

See also [Firebird for the Database Expert: Episode 6 - Why can't I shrink my databases](https://web.archive.org/web/20220524095808/https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_23).

Comment: But i work on database wich have every week delete 200000 rows and then added 200000 rows, the problem is because that database has 2.1GB and have more than 100000 problems

Comment: @TrisoftPracownicy That shouldn't matter, unless you have extremely long-living transactions that inhibit garbage collection for literally weeks. The space of deleted rows will be freed by garbage collection and reused for new rows. BTW: What do you mean with _"have more than 100000 problems"_?

Comment: After i make gfix -v -f it shows: " Number of record level errors   : 484;
                                                 Number of index page errors     : 1;
                                                 Number of database page errors  : 108829"

Comment: @TrisoftPracownicy Your database is corrupt. That has literally nothing to do with the question you asked. In any case, I suggest you take that problem to the firebird-support mailing list, make sure to include all relevant details (including errors, your full Firebird version, etc) when asking there.

Comment: Is possible that DB is corrupted because there are many transactions that not are closed  and they make something wrong ?

Comment: @TrisoftPracownicy No, unless you have hit a bug.